# Purpose of findFirst() in Realm - Android

Tags: android, realm

What is the use of `findFirst()` method in Realm for Android? Also, how to retrieve the last inserted record from a table using Realm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findFirst()` would be used when you only expect one result from your query, or just don't care about the whole list, and only want to sample one record.

If you want the very last element you could try `findAll()`, get the size of that list, and get the last element.

Comment: So by saying `one result`, which result it would be? I mean, suppose I've 5 rows in the db and I fire a findFirst() query, which row will be retrieved?

Comment: In psuedo-code. You have a list... `[1, 2, 3]` and find `where x = 2`, then `findFirst` simply returns 2.

Comment: Right. Gotcha! Thanks.

Comment: So, like, a query that does "find By Id", then that's the best use-case for `findFirst()` when your ID is unique to that data point